# PHP echo to JavaScript via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to include an echo from a php file to javascript file.

I have this code in my php-file:

```
<?php
   ...I connect and load list from database here...

   for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($list_rows);$i++) {
      echo '"'.$list_rows[$i]['name'].'": null,';
   }
?>
```

and the following code in my JavaScript file:

```
<script>
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
   data: {
      HERE I WANT TO HAVE THE ECHO
   },
});

</script>
```

The php-file is giving me the **correct** echo when I open it directly, but my javascript file don't. Can you help me?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make following changes

```
<?php
   ...I connect and load list from database here...
   $echo_text = ''; 
   for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($list_rows);$i++) {
      $echo_text .= '"'.$list_rows[$i]['name'].'": null,';
   }
?>

<script>
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
   data: {
      '<?php echo $echo_text;?>'
   },
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php code concat strings

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

   $string = "";
   for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($list_rows);$i++) {
       $string.='"'.$list_rows[$i]['name'].'": null,';
   }

?>
```

in javascript just get that php variable like this -

```
<script>
var res = '<?php echo $string; ?>';
alert(res);
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
   data: {
      res 
   },
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
   $names = [];
   for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($list_rows);$i++) {
      if($list_rows[$i]['name'] != ""){
        array_push($names, array('label' => $list_rows[$i]['name'], 'value' => $list_rows[$i]['name']));
      }
      //echo '"'.$list_rows[$i]['name'].'": null,';
   }
   $names = json_encode($names);
?>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
   data: '<?php echo $names; ?>',
});
</script>
```

More Info: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct, that I can put php via  into a javascript file?

My first idea was to load the javascript file in html and this javascript loads an external php file :/